# Beautiful Soup - Ignore child divs with same name as parent div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

the html is structured as so:

```
  <div class="my_class">
       <div>important text</div>
       <div class="my_class">
            <div>not important</div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="my_class">
       <div>important text</div>
       <div class="my_class">
            <div>not important</div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ...
```

Basically, there are many divs with the same name as their child divs, and ultimately, I want to find the "important text" which is found under the partent div only.

When I try to find all divs with class="my_class", I obviously get both the parents and the childs. How can I only get the parent divs?

Here is my code for getting all divs with class = "my_class" and finding the important text:

```
my_div_list = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'my_class'})
for my_div in my_div_list:
    text_item = my_div.find('div') # to get to the div that contains the important text
    print(text_item.getText())
```

Obviously, the output is:

```
important text
not important
important text
not important
...
```

When I want:

```
 important text
 important text
 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `findall()` documentation:

> recursive is a boolean argument (defaulting to True) which tells Beautiful Soup 
>   whether to go all the way down the parse tree, or whether to only look at the 
>   immediate children of the Tag or the parser object.

So, given the first level of divs is for example under the tags `<head>` and `<body>`, you can set

```py
soup.html.body.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'my_class'}, 
recursive=False)
```

Output:

```
 ['important text', 'important text']
```

Comment: thanks! I had to do a little editing to make it work for me (my list of div's were under another div, so i did soup.find(upper div).find_all(divs). For others reading this, for recursive to work, you need to be at the tag DIRECTLY above the tags you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over `soup.contents`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
r = [i.div.text for i in soup(html, 'html.parser').contents if i != '\n']
```

Output:

```
['important text', 'important text']
```

Answer (score 1):

with bs4 4.7.1 you can use :has and :first-child

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<div class="my_class">
       <div>important text</div>
       <div class="my_class">
            <div>not important</div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="my_class">
       <div>important text</div>
       <div class="my_class">
            <div>not important</div>
       </div>
   </div>'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
print([i.text for i in soup.select('.my_class:has(>.my_class) > div:first-child')])
```

Comment: I wish we could use the same in vba as well.